# Implementing n interface explicitly using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, properties, interface, explicit

I came across this problem when i was implementing n interface explicitly using Visual Studio. So the interface contains properties, but when I am implementing the property explicitly in an abstract class, Compiler throws error "The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item".

Refer Below given code.

```
interface ITest
{
    bool MyProperty { get; set; }
}

internal class Test : ITest
{
    public bool ITest.MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }    

        set { }
    }
}
```

Comment: So remove the `public` modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [programming guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173157.aspx), explicit interface implementations always lack an access modifier. You should remove the `public` keyword.

If you think about it, this makes a lot of sense. There is only one possible access modifier for an explicit interface implementation - the same modifier used for the interface. Thus, you don't need to specify the modifier.

If the interface is marked `public`, and the explicit implementation is `private`, that will not make sense. The only reason to write an explicit implementation is to expose that member to only that interface. It would be weird if the member is less accessible than the interface, right?

On the other hand, if the interface is `internal` and the member is marked `public`, it will not make sense either. If the member is more accessible than the interface, then it will not be exposed only to the interface.

Comment: Thank you Sweeper. You explained it very nicely. Got it!